# Showing Different Document Types in Kibana from ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I'm in the process of trying to setup a Kibana dashboard. This dashboard is hitting an ElasticSearch index. My index has the following mappings:

```
"myindex": {
  "mappings": {
    "animals": {
      "properties": {
        "@timestamp": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "dateOptionalTime"
        },
        "@version": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "Class": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "Order": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "Family": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "Genus": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "Species": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    },
    "elements" : {
      "properties": {
        "@timestamp": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "dateOptionalTime"
        },
        "@version": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "Symbol": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "Name": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "Group": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "Period": {
          "type": "string"
        }             
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As the mappings show, my index has two different types of information. My challenge is, I don't know how to setup my kibana dashboard to just list the information for each type. I've confirmed that the data in my elasticsearch instance is the correct data.

In my dashboard, I'm trying to show two tables. One table will show all of the documents associated with "animals". The other table will show all of the documents associated with "elements". Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to focus the results of a table down to a specific type. I'm basically trying to figure out how to setup either a query or a filter (not sure the difference between the two in the kibana world) for a specific panel. Currently, my dashboard looks like this:

```
{
  "title": "Research",
  "services": {
    "query": {
      "list": {
        "0": {
          "query": "*",
          "alias": "",
          "color": "#7EB26D",
          "id": 0,
          "pin": false,
          "type": "lucene"
        }
      },
      "ids": [
        0
      ]
    },
    "filter": {
      "list": {
        "0": {
          "type": "time",
          "field": "@timestamp",
          "from": "now-{{ARGS.from || '24h'}}",
          "to": "now",
          "mandate": "must",
          "active": true,
          "alias": "",
          "id": 0
        }
      },
      "ids": [
        0
      ]
    }
  },
  "rows": [
    {
      "title": "Animals",
      "height": "350px",
      "editable": true,
      "collapse": false,
      "collapsable": true,
      "panels": [
        {
          "title": "Animals",
          "error": false,
          "span": 12,
          "editable": true,
          "group": [
            "default"
          ],
          "type": "table",
          "size": 100,
          "pages": 5,
          "offset": 0,
          "sort": [
            "@timestamp",
            "desc"
          ],
          "style": {
            "font-size": "9pt"
          },
          "overflow": "min-height",
          "fields": [
            "Class",
            "Order",
            "Family",
            "Genus",
            "Species"
          ],
          "localTime": true,
          "timeField": "@timestamp",
          "highlight": [],
          "sortable": true,
          "header": true,
          "paging": true,
          "spyable": true,
          "queries": {
            "mode": "all",
            "ids": [
              0
            ]
          },
          "field_list": true,
          "status": "Stable",
          "trimFactor": 300,
          "normTimes": true
        }
      ],
      "notice": false
    },
    {
      "title": "",
      "height": "350px",
      "editable": true,
      "collapse": false,
      "collapsable": true,
      "panels": [
        {
          "title": "Elements",
          "error": false,
          "span": 12,
          "editable": true,
          "group": [
            "default"
          ],
          "type": "table",
          "size": 100,
          "pages": 5,
          "offset": 0,
          "sort": [
            "@timestamp",
            "desc"
          ],
          "style": {
            "font-size": "9pt"
          },
          "overflow": "min-height",
          "fields": [
            "Symbol",
            "Name",
            "Group",
            "Period"
          ],
          "localTime": true,
          "timeField": "@timestamp",
          "highlight": [],
          "sortable": true,
          "header": true,
          "paging": true,
          "spyable": true,
          "queries": {
            "mode": "all",
            "ids": [
              0
            ]
          },
          "field_list": true,
          "trimFactor": 300,
          "normTimes": true
        }
      ],
      "notice": false
    }    
  ],
  "editable": true,
  "failover": false,
  "index": {
    "interval": "none",
    "default": "myindex"
  },
  "style": "dark",
  "panel_hints": true,
  "pulldowns": [
    {
      "type": "query",
      "collapse": false,
      "notice": false,
      "query": "*",
      "pinned": true,
      "history": [],
      "remember": 10
    },
    {
      "type": "filtering",
      "collapse": true,
      "notice": false
    }
  ],
  "loader": {
    "save_gist": false,
    "save_elasticsearch": true,
    "save_local": true,
    "save_default": true,
    "save_temp": true,
    "save_temp_ttl_enable": true,
    "save_temp_ttl": "30d",
    "load_gist": true,
    "load_elasticsearch": true,
    "load_elasticsearch_size": 20,
    "load_local": true,
    "hide": false
  },
  "refresh": "30s"
}
```

Can someone tell me how to show two different types of documents in Kibana? I see a queries object on the table panel. Yet, I have no idea how to use it.

Thank you so much

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the ***_type*** field to narrow the result to a specific elastic search type (e.g. animals).

So when you define the query (or filter) for your table, just make sure to specify the relevant `_type` (i.e. `_type: animals`)

Answer (score 1):

You can use scripted fields to have value of type as separate field which will be indexed.

or you can add ***_type*** field to search field it will be available.

In case of scripted fields add as `doc['_type'].value` and give it any name you want.

https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/5684